# How to find the domain in $f(x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{| \arcsin |x||}+\frac{|\arccos|x||}{\arccos|x|}+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

The problem is as follows:

> Find the range in the following function:
>
> $f(x)=\frac{\arcsin x}{| \arcsin |x||}+\frac{|\arccos|x||}{\arccos|x|}+1$
>
> $\begin{array}{ll}
> 1.&\{3,1\}\\
> 2.&\left\{\frac{1}{3},1\right\}\\
> 3.&\{1,2\}\\
> 4.&\{3,2\}\\
> \end{array}$

Gee. I'm confused with so many absolute values exactly on what should be done here to solve this problem. Can someone help me here?. I think the most misleading part here is the brackets used. I have no idea on its meaning.

Can someone help me on how to solve this thing without much fuss?.

Comment: start one by one: what is the domain of $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$? What is the domain of absolute value $|\cdot|$? When does division make sense?

Comment: why are u asking domain in title and range in description?

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\arccos |x|\in[0,\pi]$, and so is always non-negative. This means the second term is $1$. Secondly, $\arcsin |x| \ge 0$ as the $\arcsin$ of a positive number is positive, so $|\arcsin |x| | =\arcsin|x|$. $$f(x) =2+\frac{\arcsin x}{\arcsin|x|} $$ Now, when $x\le 0$, $\arcsin |x| =-\arcsin x$ and when $x\ge 0$, $\arcsin|x| =\arcsin x$. Therefore $f(x)$ can take either of the values $1$ and $3$.

Answer (score 0):

ok so range:
$\dfrac{a}{|a|} = \dfrac{|a|}{a} = 1 \text{ if } a>0, -1 \text{ if } a<0$

since $\arccos|x|> 0$ for all $x$ in its domain, $\dfrac{|\arccos|x||}{\arccos|x|} = 1$

as for $\dfrac{\arcsin(x)}{|\arcsin|x||}$, this can be either 1 or -1 depending of the value of x.

So your function has two cases:

$\{-1+1+1, 1+1+1\} = \{1,3\}$